# Sort rows with same value counts

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe

I want to sort a pandas dataframe by count of a value in a column. For values with the same count, I want them clustered, and sorted alphabetically.

I tried different settings with the `sort` call. I also tried first sorting the dataframe alphabetically, and next by count.

Here's the relevant section of the code I currently use:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("filename.csv")
df['Counts'] = df.groupby(['Words']).transform('count')
df.sort_values('Counts', inplace=True, ascending=False)
print(df)
```

What I get is something like:

```
    
    
        Words   Counts
    1   Alpha    2
    2   Beta     2
    3   Charlie  2
    4   Alpha    2
    5   Beta     2
    6   Charlie  2
    7   Delta    1
```

What I want is:

```
    
    
        Words   Counts
    1   Alpha    2
    2   Alpha    2
    3   Beta     2
    4   Beta     2
    5   Charlie  2
    6   Charlie  2
    7   Delta    1
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Sort by both count *and* words: `df.sort_values(['Counts', 'Words'], inplace=True, ascending=[False, True])`

Comment: Wow, so simple! Thank you!